# Background Color not being set in WP Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to set up background color and image controls for a particular element (.site-header) on a WordPress site using WP Customizer.

The background image is functioning fine - both preview and actually writing the CSS to head. But for the background color, only the preview works but it does not actually get applied. After clicking 'Save & Publish' button and the X button, browser shows:

[image]

When 'Leave this Page' is clicked, the background color set in the customizer does not appear on the front end for the .site-header element.

Code in functions.php:

```
/**
 * HEX Color sanitization callback example.
 *
 * - Sanitization: hex_color
 * - Control: text, WP_Customize_Color_Control
 *
 * Note: sanitize_hex_color_no_hash() can also be used here, depending on whether
 * or not the hash prefix should be stored/retrieved with the hex color value.
 *
 * @see sanitize_hex_color() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_hex_color/
 * @link sanitize_hex_color_no_hash() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_hex_color_no_hash/
 *
 * @param string               $hex_color HEX color to sanitize.
 * @param WP_Customize_Setting $setting   Setting instance.
 * @return string The sanitized hex color if not null; otherwise, the setting default.
 */
function sk_sanitize_hex_color( $hex_color, $setting ) {
    // Sanitize $input as a hex value without the hash prefix.
    $hex_color = sanitize_hex_color( $hex_color );

    // If $input is a valid hex value, return it; otherwise, return the default.
    return ( ! null( $hex_color ) ? $hex_color : $setting->default );
}


/**
 * Image sanitization callback example.
 *
 * Checks the image's file extension and mime type against a whitelist. If they're allowed,
 * send back the filename, otherwise, return the setting default.
 *
 * - Sanitization: image file extension
 * - Control: text, WP_Customize_Image_Control
 *
 * @see wp_check_filetype() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_filetype/
 *
 * @param string               $image   Image filename.
 * @param WP_Customize_Setting $setting Setting instance.
 * @return string The image filename if the extension is allowed; otherwise, the setting default.
 */
function sk_sanitize_image( $image, $setting ) {

    /*
     * Array of valid image file types.
     *
     * The array includes image mime types that are included in wp_get_mime_types()
     */
    $mimes = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif'          => 'image/gif',
        'png'          => 'image/png',
        'bmp'          => 'image/bmp',
        'tif|tiff'     => 'image/tiff',
        'ico'          => 'image/x-icon'
    );

    // Return an array with file extension and mime_type.
    $file = wp_check_filetype( $image, $mimes );

    // If $image has a valid mime_type, return it; otherwise, return the default.
    return ( $file['ext'] ? $image : $setting->default );
}


/**
 * Customizer: Add Sections
 *
 * This file demonstrates how to add Sections to the Customizer
 *
 * @package   code-examples
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015, WordPress Theme Review Team
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU General Public License, v2 (or newer)
 */


/**
 * Theme Options Customizer Implementation.
 *
 * Implement the Theme Customizer for Theme Settings.
 *
 * @link http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize Object that holds the customizer data.
 */
function sk_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

    /*
     * Failsafe is safe
     */
    if ( ! isset( $wp_customize ) ) {
        return;
    }


    /**
     * Add Header Section for General Options.
     *
     * @uses $wp_customize->add_section() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_section/
     * @link $wp_customize->add_section() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section
     */
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        // $id
        'sk_section_header',
        // $args
        array(
            'title'         => __( 'Header Background', 'theme-slug' ),
            'description'   => __( 'Set background color and/or background image for the header', 'theme-slug' ),
            // 'panel'          => 'sk_panel_general'
        )
    );


    /**
     * Header Background Color setting.
     *
     * - Setting: Header Background Color
     * - Control: WP_Customize_Color_Control
     * - Sanitization: hex_color
     *
     * Uses a color wheel to configure the Header Background Color setting.
     *
     * @uses $wp_customize->add_setting() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/
     * @link $wp_customize->add_setting() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting
     */
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        // $id
        'header_background_color',
        // $args
        array(
            'default'           => '',
            'type'              => 'theme_mod',
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sk_sanitize_hex_color',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage'
        )
    );


    /**
     * Header Background Image setting.
     *
     * - Setting: Header Background Image
     * - Control: WP_Customize_Image_Control
     * - Sanitization: image
     *
     * Uses the media manager to upload and select an image to be used as the header background image.
     *
     * @uses $wp_customize->add_setting() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/
     * @link $wp_customize->add_setting() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting
     */
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        // $id
        'header_background_image',
        // $args
        array(
            'default'           => '',
            'type'              => 'theme_mod',
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sk_sanitize_image',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage'
        )
    );

    /**
     * Core Color control.
     *
     * - Control: Color
     * - Setting: Header Background Color
     * - Sanitization: hex_color
     *
     * Register "WP_Customize_Color_Control" to be used to configure the Header Background Color setting.
     *
     * @uses $wp_customize->add_control() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/
     * @link $wp_customize->add_control() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control
     *
     * @uses WP_Customize_Color_Control() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_color_control/
     * @link WP_Customize_Color_Control() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Color_Control
     */
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            // $wp_customize object
            $wp_customize,
            // $id
            'header_background_color',
            // $args
            array(
                'settings'      => 'header_background_color',
                'section'       => 'sk_section_header',
                'label'         => __( 'Header Background Color', 'theme-slug' ),
                'description'   => __( 'Select the background color for header.', 'theme-slug' )
            )
        )
    );


    /**
     * Image Upload control.
     *
     * Control: Image Upload
     * Setting: Header Background Image
     * Sanitization: image
     *
     * Register "WP_Customize_Image_Control" to be used to configure the Header Background Image setting.
     *
     * @uses $wp_customize->add_control() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/
     * @link $wp_customize->add_control() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control
     *
     * @uses WP_Customize_Image_Control() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_image_control/
     * @link WP_Customize_Image_Control() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Image_Control
     */
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            // $wp_customize object
            $wp_customize,
            // $id
            'header_background_image',
            // $args
            array(
                'settings'      => 'header_background_image',
                'section'       => 'sk_section_header',
                'label'         => __( 'Header Background Image', 'theme-slug' ),
                'description'   => __( 'Select the background image for header.', 'theme-slug' )
            )
        )
    );


}

// Settings API options initilization and validation.
add_action( 'customize_register', 'sk_register_theme_customizer' );


/**
 * Registers the Theme Customizer Preview with WordPress.
 *
 * @package    sk
 * @since      0.3.0
 * @version    0.3.0
 */
function sk_customizer_live_preview() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'sk-theme-customizer',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js',
        array( 'customize-preview' ),
        '0.1.0',
        true
    );
} // end sk_customizer_live_preview
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'sk_customizer_live_preview' );


/**
 * Writes the Header Background Color and/or Image out to the 'head' element of the document
 * by reading the value(s) from the theme mod value in the options table.
 */
function sk_customizer_css() {
?>
     <style type="text/css">
        .site-header {
            background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_background_color' ); ?>;
        }

        <?php if ( 0 < count( strlen( ( $header_background_image_url = get_theme_mod( 'header_background_image' ) ) ) ) ) { ?>
            .site-header {
                background-image: url( <?php echo $header_background_image_url; ?> );
            }
        <?php } // end if ?>
     </style>
<?php
} // end sk_customizer_css

add_action( 'wp_head', 'sk_customizer_css');
```

Code in js/theme-customizer.js:

```
(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    // Header Background Color - Color Control
    wp.customize( 'header_background_color', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( to ) {
            $( '.site-header' ).css( 'backgroundColor', to );
        } );
    });

    // Header Background Image - Image Control
    wp.customize( 'header_background_image', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( to ) {
            $( '.site-header' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + to + ')' );
        } );
    });


})( jQuery );
```

Any idea?

I followed http://code.tutsplus.com/series/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-theme-customizer--wp-33722 and https://github.com/WPTRT/code-examples/tree/master/customizer.

Comment: You forgot to add the **'#'**. I think that code will be this


`.site-header {
    background-color: #<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_background_color' ); ?>;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I modified two things

One:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    // $id
    'header_background_color',
    // $args
    array(
        'default'           => '',
        'type'              => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage'
    )
);
```

Two:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
        // $wp_customize object
        $wp_customize,
        // $id
        'header_background_color',
        // $args
        array(
            'settings'      => 'header_background_color',
            'section'       => 'sk_section_header',
            'label'         => __( 'Header Background Color', 'theme-slug' ),
            'description'   => __( 'Select the background color for header.', 'theme-slug' ),
            'type'          => 'color',

        )
    )
);
```